# Display Notification only once with Alarmmanager (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to show notification on a specific time. So I created this function:

```
fun specificTime() {
    val _intent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, _intent, 0)
    val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent)
}
```

It works perfectly. When the time arrives, the application shows the notification and everything is good. The problem is now, when I open the app later again, he display the notification again. I'm confused, because as you can see on the function, I've give the the notification a specific hour and time, so I don't understand why he show me the notification again, even when I open the app 10min later. I added to the Notification the line `.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)`, but the result is the same.

**UPDATE (1)**

The problem is the last line of the function `alarmManager.set(...)`. The documentation says:

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately.

I tried to replace it with `alarmManager.setExact(...)`, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below Method works me fine try it

```
public void notifyAlarm(){

    Intent Alarmintent = new Intent(this,NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,Alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //set up the alarm Manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    if (calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    assert alarmManager != null;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: Sorry this code is based in java but Android Studio convert for you into Kotlin

Comment: Could you please explain me this line `if (calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`

Comment: It checks if the current time is past 21. If yes then it  adds another day to it.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I found a better solution (for me). However your answer is also correct, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
val timeUntilAlert: Long
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() < calendar.getTimeInMillis()){
        timeUntilAlert = calendar.getTimeInMillis()
    } else{
        timeUntilAlert = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000
    }

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeUntilAlert, pendingIntent)
```

Thanks to [this dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51597442/11720147) here. The answer from @Jimale Abdi is very similar.